# Meteor Collection Find Documents Based on Latest Date Time in an Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**How to get the latest documents from a collection using date time?**

I have searched in SO for this specific problem, but couldn't find an example that is similar to my data structure. I have this kind of data structure:

```
[
   {
      stationId: 'xxxxx',
      stationName:  'xxxx',
      state: 'xxxx',
      lat: 'xxxxx',
      long: 'xx.xxxxx',
      waterLevel: [
         {
              wlDateTime: '11/04/2022 11:30',
              wlSeverity: 'Danger',
              wlLevel: 7.5
         },
         {
              wlDateTime: '11/04/2022 09:00',
              wlSeverity: 'Danger',
              wlLevel: 7.3
         },
         {
              wlDateTime: '11/04/2022 03:00',
              wlSeverity: 'Normal',
              wlLevel: 5.2
         }
      ],
      rainfallData: [
         {
              rfDateTime: '11/04/2022 11:30',
              rfSeverity: 'Heavy',
              rfLevel: 21
         },
         {
              rfDateTime: '11/04/2022 10:30',
              rfSeverity: 'Heavy',
              rfLevel: 21
         },
         {
              rfDateTime: '11/04/2022 9:30',
              rfSeverity: 'Heavy',
              rfLevel: 21
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The question is, how can I get documents that have `wlDateTime` equal today, with `wlSeverity` equal to `Danger`, but I just want the latest record from the `waterLevel` array. The same case with the `rainfallData`array i.e. to return with the latest reading for today.

Sample expected return will be like this:

```
[
   {
      stationId: 'xxxxx',
      stationName:  'xxxx',
      state: 'xxxx',
      lat: 'xxxxx',
      long: 'xx.xxxxx',
      waterLevelData: [
         {
              wlDateTime: '11/04/2022 11:30',  //latest data compared to the array
              wlSeverity: 'Danger',
              wlLevel: 7.5
         }
      ],
      rainfallData: [
         {
              rfDateTime: '11/04/2022 11:30', //latest data compared to the array
              rfSeverity: 'Heavy',
              rfLevel: 21
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I've tried querying it like this:

```
    Meteor.publish('Alerts', function(){
      return AlertLatest.find({
        'waterLevelData.wlSeverity':'Danger',
      }, {
        fields : {
        'stationName'               : 1,
        'state'                     : 1,
        'lat'                       : 1,
        'long'                      : 1,
        'waterLevelData.wlDateTime' : 1,
        'waterLevelData.wlSeverity' : 1,
        'waterLevelData.wlLevel'    : 1,
        'rainfallData.rfSeverity'   : 1,      
      }},{sort: { 'waterLevelData.wlDateTime' : -1}});
    })
```

but the query returned data that isn't how I wanted. Any help will be much appreciated.

## ***UPDATE***

I've tried the solution provided by @YuTing, which is using aggregate to customise the publication query. I went ahead and read a bit about Mongodb Aggregation, and found a Meteorjs community package ([tunguska:reactive-aggregate](https://github.com/robfallows/tunguska-reactive-aggregate)) which simplifies the process.

This is the sample of a working aggregation so far:

```
Meteor.publish('PIBDataAlerts', function(){
      const start = dayjs().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
      const end = dayjs().endOf('day'); // set to 23:59 pm today
      ReactiveAggregate(this, PIBLatest, [
        {
          $match: {   
            'stationStatus' : 'ON',
            'waterLevelData': {        //trying to get only today's docs
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "wlDateTime" : {
                        $gte: start.format()  , $lt: end.format()  
                    }
                }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            waterLevelHFZ: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$waterLevelData",
                as: "w",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    { $or : [
                      { $eq: [ "$$w.wlSeverity", "Alert" ] },
                      { $eq: [ "$$w.wlSeverity", "Warning" ] },
                      { $eq: [ "$$w.wlSeverity", "Danger" ] },
                    ]},
                    { $eq: [ "$$w.wlDateTime", { $max: "$waterLevelData.wlDateTime" } ] }
                  ],
                }
              }
            },
            rainfallDataHFZ: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$rainfallData",
                as: "r",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$r.rfDateTime", { $max: "$rainfallData.rfDateTime" } ] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project : {
            "stationId": 1,
            "stationName" :1,
            "state": 1,
            "waterLevelHFZ": 1,
            "rainfallDataHFZ": 1
          }
        }
      ]);
    })
```

I'm struggling to get documents that only have the `wlDateTime` that equals today. I've tried a query in the `$match` but it returned empty array. If the `$match` is set to `{}`, it'll return all 1548 records even though the `wlDateTime` is not equals to today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change your date string to date
2. filter the array to find the max one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$waterLevel",
                  as: "w",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $dateTrunc: {
                          date: {
                            $dateFromString: {
                              dateString: "$$w.wlDateTime",
                              format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
                            }
                          },
                          unit: "day"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        $dateTrunc: {
                          date: "$$NOW",
                          unit: "day"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$rainfallData",
                  as: "r",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $dateTrunc: {
                          date: {
                            $dateFromString: {
                              dateString: "$$r.rfDateTime",
                              format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
                            }
                          },
                          unit: "day"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        $dateTrunc: {
                          date: "$$NOW",
                          unit: "day"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      waterLevel: {
        $map: {
          input: "$waterLevel",
          as: "w",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$w",
              {
                wlDateTime: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$$w.wlDateTime",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      rainfallData: {
        $map: {
          input: "$rainfallData",
          as: "r",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$r",
              {
                rfDateTime: {
                  $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$$r.rfDateTime",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      waterLevel: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$waterLevel",
          as: "w",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$w.wlSeverity",
                  [
                    "Alert",
                    "Warning",
                    "Danger"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$w.wlDateTime",
                  {
                    $max: "$waterLevel.wlDateTime"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$w.wlDateTime",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$NOW",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      rainfallData: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$rainfallData",
          as: "r",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$r.rfDateTime",
                  {
                    $max: "$rainfallData.rfDateTime"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$r.rfDateTime",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$NOW",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NROy4uP7VEa)

Comment: i've tried your way using the aggregate. I think it can solve my problem, but I'm now facing another problem filtering the returned data. I only want the publication to return today's data (and the latest, since today might have few object entries in the 'waterLevelData' array). Can you help? I've included the latest code above.

Comment: @HafizHanif i update my answer, I add `$match` and `$filter` to get only `TODAY`. And I change `$toDate` to `$dateFromString`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can sort by embedded document in an array field. It's not how mongodb works.

Answer (score 0):

> but I just want the latest

I you are only interested in the latest docs you can omit the `sort` and instead use a natural negative cursor:

```js
Meteor.publish('Alerts', function(){
  return AlertLatest.find({
    'waterLevelData.wlSeverity':'Danger',
  }, {
    fields : {
    'stationName'               : 1,
    'state'                     : 1,
    'lat'                       : 1,
    'long'                      : 1,
    'waterLevelData.wlDateTime' : 1,
    'waterLevelData.wlSeverity' : 1,
    'waterLevelData.wlLevel'    : 1,
    'rainfallData.rfSeverity'   : 1,      
  }},{ hint: { $natural: -1}});
})
```

It will start counting docs from the end, instead of the beginning.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find